# Ansible's display_args_to_stdout but only for the args that I have set myself, not all the default ones

Tags: ansible

When `ansible-playbook` is running, by default it prints out the `name` field, with [`display_args_to_stdout`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#display-args-to-stdout), it shows the variables used, which is helpful so you don't need to set a `name`. But it displays too much info. Can I make it show only the variables/arguments that I set in the task?

e.g. This playbook task:

```
- lineinfile:
    line: alias ll="ls -lhtr"
    path: /root/.bashrc
```

is displayed like this by default (i.e. with `ANSIBLE_DISPLAY_ARGS_TO_STDOUT=no`):

```
TASK [lineinfile] ************
ok: [server1]
```

When I turn on `ANSIBLE_DISPLAY_ARGS_TO_STDOUT=yes`, it's displayed like this:

```
TASK [lineinfile line=alias ll="ls -lhtr", path=/root/.bashrc, _ansible_check_mode=True, _ansible_no_log=False, _ansible_debug=False, _ansible_diff=True, _ansible_verbosity=0, _ansible_version=2.9.9, _ansible_module_name=lineinfile, _ansible_syslog_facility=LOG_USER, _ansible_selinux_special_fs=['fuse', 'nfs', 'vboxsf', 'ramfs', '9p', 'vfat'], _ansible_string_conversion_action=warn, _ansible_socket=None, _ansible_shell_executable=/bin/sh, _ansible_keep_remote_files=False, _ansible_tmpdir=None, _ansible_remote_tmp=~/.ansible/tmp] ***
ok: [server1]
```

which includes loads of variables for every task (e.g. `_ansible_selinux_special_fs=…`). Is it possible to instead make it display this:

```
TASK [lineinfile line=alias ll="ls -lhtr", path=/root/.bashrc] ******
ok: [server1]
```

I am using ansible (v2.9.9) on ubuntu linux 18.04

Answer (score 1):

> Q: *" Display: TASK [lineinfile line=alias ll="ls -lhtr", path=/root/.bashrc]"*

A: There is no such [callback plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/callback.html#plugin-list) but it's possible to [develop](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_plugins.html) it. There are 2 simpler solutions.

---

Put the variables into the `name`. For example

```yaml
    - name: "lineinfile line={{ my_line }}, path={{ my_path }}"
      lineinfile:
        line: "{{ my_line }}"
        path: "{{ my_path }}"
      vars:
        my_line: alias ll="ls -lhtr"
        my_path: /root/.bashrc
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [lineinfile line=alias ll="ls -lhtr", path=/root/.bashrc] ****
changed: [localhost]
```

---

Next option is `loop_control` `label`. For example

```yaml
    - lineinfile:
        line: "{{ item.my_line }}"
        path: "{{ item.my_path }}"
      loop: "{{ my_lines }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "lineinfile line={{ item.my_line }}, path={{ item.my_path }}"
      vars:
        my_lines:
          - {my_line: alias ll="ls -lhtr", my_path: /root/.bashrc}
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [lineinfile] ****
changed: [localhost] => (item=lineinfile line=alias ll="ls -lhtr", path=/root/.bashrc)
```

Comment: Thanks.I'm aware I could use `name`, but I want something more automatic. Maybe I will develop such a plugin